# How to get the xml header/parent tag to a variable in perl?

Tags: xml, perl

I am new to `Perl`

```
<nst:root arg='1' arg2='2' arg3='3'>
   <a>1</a>
   <b>2</b>
</nst:root>
```

I want 2 variable like,

```
$root = '<nst:root arg='1' arg2='2' arg3='3'>';
$rootClose = '</nst:root>';
```

I want a regular expression for this. Because I can not read line by line. My xml file can be like below also

```
<nst:root arg='1' arg2='2' arg3='3'><a>1</a><b>2</b></nst:root>
```

I don't want to read a full file. Because I have 100's of file and one file contains more than 10k line.

Comment: You do not want to do this with regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: My aim is to strip the header tag from the XML. Please help me doing this

Comment: How to remove the parent tag from the xml?

Comment: I have an other question that is answered ...

Comment: That is my question only, but did not get any answer

Comment: How to remove the parent tags from the XML ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
open(my $fh,"<your file name");
while(<$fh>){
   $test=$_;
   if ($test =~ /([^>]*)>.*<([^>]*)/g) {
      print qq{$1>  <$2>};
   }
last;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my aim is to update one xml file with other xml. Please help

Comment: Example, I want to update the root tag `<root>` with `<nst:root arg='1' arg2='2' arg3='3'>`

Comment: See this is what I wanted to do. I have an xml file and that has actual root tag. I split that file in to multiple using XML::Twig::xml_split. I get many files but header is different. I want to update the child file with actual header from mail file.

Comment: You should have said so in the first place.